# need raw query to show flagged emails OR emails with red category

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2016, office-for-mac

what's the proper raw query for me to utilize if I wanted to show only emails I've flagged OR emails I've categorized with the red color? I'd like to pull both these types of emails in one smart folder

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can use Outlook Search Folder. For your reference:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ccaef4e9-76eb-4edb-ade7-d7cb3d383821/outlook-desktop-client-categories-into-favorites?forum=outlook

Comment: @Aidan don’t think you can perform OR logic with search folders. if you add multiple criteria, it performs AND logic.  reference: https://superuser.com/questions/1104727/in-outlook-2016-for-mac-how-do-i-find-all-emails-containing-either-a-or-b-a